# Noise when the engine is idle

Tags: engine, clutch, noise

I would like to know why my car is making noise when the engine is idle, but the noise is silence when I pressed the clutch ?

Comment: This isn't really about maintenance or repair... That is normal behaviour, it is because the gearbox is turning when it's connected to the engine, and not when you disconnect it by pressing the clutch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With the lack of information you've (haven't) provided**, there is only one thing which I can think of which might be causing the noise you are describing, and that is if the main bearing in the front of the transmission is going out. When you push in the clutch pedal, the transmission is disconnected from the engine and is therefor not turning. When the transmission is in gear and the clutch engaged, the front bearing will not usually make any noise due to the torque applied to the main shaft. That is at least at first until the bearing gets bad enough to be making noise all the time. If this truly is the problem, it can only be solved by taking the vehicle to a mechanic for a transmission rebuild.

Comment: My friend just told me it's probably clutch bearing problem. I really didn't have any mechanical skills, so I'm really confused about this. I think I better bring this to garage.

Comment: If it were a clutch (or throwout) bearing problem, *it would happen as you press the pedal*, not when you release it. It has to come from the transmissions side since it is only making the noise when the transmission is engaged. The throwout bearing is only working when you press the clutch pedal. It is at rest when the pedal is at rest. It is what makes contact with the clutch forks to disengage the pressure plate allowing clutch release.

Comment: I have brought the car to the garage. The mechanic told me it's the gearbox bearing problem. You're right about it. Thanks.

Comment: @bsentosa ... Well, sometimes I wish I weren't right, because I know how costly it is to fix.

Comment: Hi @Paulster2 is it dangerous to drive the car without being fixed ?

Comment: @bsentosa ... It's not dangerous for you, but you run the risk of damaging the transmission further. One of the jobs of the bearing is to keep things aligned in the transmission. If the shafts get out of alignment, adverse wear will start occurring on the "hard parts" or gears. This wear is irreversible and will require gear replacement at some point. The wear can get to a point where you won't be able to shift gears at some point, thus leaving you stranded when you least expect it.

Comment: You are really good. Thank you very much. I have replaced the gearbox bearing. I just know it, this is common issues in Honda Jazz 2002-2008 (same problem with Civic too) due to bad batch in manufacturing process. Honda extend the warranty for this issue up to 100K miles or 7 years by issuing Service Bulletin. But since my car is out of warranty then I have to fix it by my pocket. Luckily I found a local gearbox specialist that can fix it without a middle-man (most of the garage in my area are just taken the fee to take off and fitting the gearbox, sending them to the specialist